# How come my Raphael.js circle object is not getting its 'attr' changes animated & not getting the jQuery HandlerOut event object applied to it?

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-selectors, raphael

I have created a `#logo` DIV that consists of a smaller `#circle` DIV & `h1`. The `#circle` acts as the DIV/canvas that my Raphael.js object, a circle, is rendered in. My goal was to make it so when a user hovers over the `#logo` DIV the Raphael.js circle and `h1` will get animated but I ran into some problems.

- For some reason my Raphael.js circle object is not getting it's `.attr()` method animated during a jQuery `.hover()` `handlerIn` mouse event. The change just happens immediately.
- Additionally, during the `handlerOut` event, the Raphael.js circle does not get its `.attr()` method applied to it at all. It just keeps the `.attr()` attributes that were applied to it during the `handerIn` event

The code to [my example of this issue is located here](http://jsbin.com/oxano3/3/edit). You can click preview (top right) at that page to see the code in action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(c.node).animate({fill: "#666"}, 2000);
```

This is jQuery animation. Obviously jQuery has no idea about Raphaël objects. Use Raphaël animation instead:

```
c.animate({fill: "#666"}, 2000);
```

General advice don’t touch node property unless you really really know what you doing.

Comment: Thanks. Now the circle is getting its attributes changed during handlerIn & handlerOut events but now the cursor over the SVG circle disappears. Is there a Raphael method I can place following the animate method to have the arrow cursor change to a pointer/hand cursor? Or should I just put $(c.node).css('cursor','pointer'); on the line after c.animate({fill: "#666"}, 2000); ?